# slideDown doesn't "hide" the element

Tags: jquery, hide, slide, effect, drawer

The animation I wanted to show/hide the order form works perfectly except one issue, the form does not hide on sliding down, a part of it is still visible.

HTML:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
        <a href="" class="order"></a>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="order-form">
        <a href="" class="close"></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".post .order").click(function () {
          $(this).fadeOut();
          $(this).parents('.post-content').slideUp();
          $(this).parents('.post-content').next('.order-form').show();
          $(this).parents().find('.close').fadeIn();
          return false;
    });
    $(".order-form .close").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $(this).parents('.order-form').slideDown();
        $(this).parents('.order-form').prev('.post-content').slideDown(function(){
            $(this).parents('.order-form').prev('.post-content').css('display', 'none');
        });
        $(this).parents().find('.order').fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
```

.. as you can see I tried `.hide()` but that doesn't work as expected, it disabled the slidedown animation which is required for a neat drawer (right word?) like effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRh3P/). What's the CSS?

Comment: try to change the slideDown() to slideUp(), http://jsfiddle.net/2yrj6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2yrj6/2/ 
but I don't know if that's what you want

Comment: Woah, that was so simple! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're calling `$(this).parents('.order-form').prev('.post-content').css('display', 'none');` inside a callback function. Except, `$(this)` is no longer the close button. It is the element which was just hidden. Try declaring var `$this` in the first line of your click callback. Then use `$this` instead of `$(this)`.

Other notes:
You should do `parents('.post')` instead of `parents()` for better performance.
You can use `.hide()` instead of `.css('display', 'none')`.